# Replace default WPF theme Style for all controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I tried to replace the default style at my WPF project for all my controls.
I created a `ResourceDictionary` like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type Button}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and in my `App.Xaml` I wrote this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries >
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="pack://application:,,,/MYTestTheme;component/Themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now in my `MainWindow.Xaml` I created a button and the style was on it.
I want to crate a new button `MyButton` who inherited from button

And I want every `Button` defined style will be on `MyButton` when I place it on my `MainWindow.Xaml` but that does not happen.

One more important thing I don't want to use `BasedOn`.

I was see this code at some blogas:

```
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source=”{ThemeDictionary MyApplication}”/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

But it's not worked!!!

Thanks

Comment: _One more important thing I don't want to use BasedOn_ why not?

Answer (score 0):

Give your key a string name:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

And add this in the App.XAML (outside your Application.Resources block):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButton}" />
```

Comment: I was see this code at some blogas:

<Application>
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source=”{ThemeDictionary MyApplication}”/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
But it's not worked!!!